# Why is the method not available when I implemented the trait that provides it?

Tags: rust

I am implementing a small thing that creates bytes representations for practicing and have 2 structures for it. The struc that receices a Generic would in the future accept vectors or other types, in this case in my code I have it for u8 for I want to be able to accept a vector of `&str` later on like `<VecBinaryByte<&str>>::new(vec!["0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1"])`, and this is why it's a generic struct.

```
struct StrBinaryByte(String);
struct VecBinaryByte<T>(Vec<T>);
```

I just want to be able to compare them this way as their representation is technically the same:

```
let byte1 = StrBinaryByte::new("00010111");
let byte2 = <VecBinaryByte<u8>>::new(vec![0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]);

if byte1 == byte1 {
    println!("byte1 == byte1");
}
    
if  byte2 == byte1 {
    println!("byte1 == byte2");
}
```

But I am unable to make this work.

This is all my code:

```
trait ByteRepToU8 {
    fn to_u8(&self) -> u8;
}

struct StrBinaryByte(String);
struct VecBinaryByte<T>(Vec<T>);

impl ByteRepToU8 for VecBinaryByte<u8> {
    fn to_u8(&self) -> u8 {
        let mut result: u8 = 0;
        for (i, bit) in self.0.iter().rev().enumerate() {
            if *bit == 0 {
                result += 0
            } else { // bit == 1
                result += 2u8.pow(i as u32)
            }
        }

        result
    }
}

impl ByteRepToU8 for StrBinaryByte {
     fn to_u8(&self) -> u8 {
        eval_char_vector(self.0.chars().rev().collect::<Vec<_>>().iter())
    }
}

impl StrBinaryByte {
    fn new(s: &str) -> StrBinaryByte {
        if s.len() != 8 {
            panic!("String must be 8 characters long")
        }

        // can contain only 1 or 0
        if s.chars().any(|c| c != '0' && c != '1') {
            panic!("String must contain only 1 or 0")
        }

        StrBinaryByte(s.to_string())
    }
}

impl VecBinaryByte<u8> {
    fn new(v: Vec<u8>) -> VecBinaryByte<u8> {
        if v.len() != 8 {
            panic!("Vector must be 8 characters long")
        }
        
        // can contain only 1 or 0
        if v.iter().any(|c| *c != 0 && *c != 1) {
            panic!("Vector must contain only 1 or 0")
        }

        VecBinaryByte(v)
    }
}

fn eval_char_vector<'c, T: Iterator<Item=&'c char>>(list: T) -> u8 {
    let mut result = 0;

    for (i, bit) in  list.enumerate() {
        if *bit == '0' {
            result += 0
        } else { // bit == '1'
            result += 2u8.pow(i as u32);
        }
    }

    result
}

impl<T: ByteRepToU8> PartialEq<T> for StrBinaryByte {
    fn eq(&self, other: &T) -> bool {
        self.to_u8() == other.to_u8()
    }
}

// IMPLEMENTATION FOR VecBinaryByte<T> THAT I TRIED TO DO BUT FAILED
impl<T> PartialEq<StrBinaryByte> for VecBinaryByte<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &StrBinaryByte) -> bool {
        self.to_u8() == other.to_u8() 
        // ^^^^^ method not found in `&VecBinaryByte<T>`
        // error[E0599]: no method named `to_u8` found for reference `&VecBinaryByte<T>` in the current scope

    }
}

fn main() {
    let byte1 = StrBinaryByte::new("00010111");
    let byte2 = <VecBinaryByte<u8>>::new(vec![0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]);

    if byte1 == byte1 {
        println!("byte1 == byte1");
    }
    
    if  byte2 == byte1 {
        println!("byte1 == byte2");
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

^^^^^ method not found in `&VecBinaryByte<T>`
error[E0599]: no method named `to_u8` found for reference `&VecBinaryByte<T>` in the current scope

I tried this to dereference the value but it didnt work:

```
impl<T> PartialEq<StrBinaryByte> for VecBinaryByte<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &StrBinaryByte) -> bool {
        (*self).to_u8() == other.to_u8()
                ^^^^^ method not found in `VecBinaryByte<T>`
    }
}
```

And the following for example works for the compiler:

```
impl<T> PartialEq<StrBinaryByte> for VecBinaryByte<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &StrBinaryByte) -> bool {
        true
    }
}
```

Could someone please point out what could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented `ByteRepToU8` or provided a method `to_u8` for any `VecBinaryByte<T>` only one for a very specific value of `T`, `u8`, so either you provide the method for any `T` which will certanly prove very hard unless you're fine with some default, or you limit your `PartialEq` to the specific `VecBinaryByte<u8>`:

```rust
impl PartialEq<StrBinaryByte> for VecBinaryByte<u8> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &StrBinaryByte) -> bool {
        self.to_u8() == other.to_u8()
    }
}
```

A third option is to implement for `T` and limit the value of `T` to ones that can for example be converted to `u8` in *both* places:

```rust
impl<T: Into<u8> + Copy> ByteRepToU8 for VecBinaryByte<T> {
    fn to_u8(&self) -> u8 {
        let mut result: u8 = 0;
        for (i, bit) in self.0.iter().rev().enumerate() {
            let bit = (*bit).into();
            if bit == 0 {
                result += 0
            } else {
                // bit == 1
                result += 2u8.pow(i as u32)
            }
        }
        result
    }
}
//…
impl<T: Into<u8> + Copy> PartialEq<StrBinaryByte> for VecBinaryByte<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &StrBinaryByte) -> bool {
        self.to_u8() == other.to_u8()
    }
}
```